# Generate N pairs of checkboxes and N textboxes

Tags: c#, html, razor

I've written a piece of code, where a pair of checkboxes and a textbox are generated N amount of times. Depending on what's in the DB, the checkbox/textbox may have a default value or are left empty.

I've pasted the code below, could anyone take a look to see if I haven't created an abomination?

```
<td>
    @if (singleItem != null && singleItem.FolderRead)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="canRead_@item.SecureFolderID" class="CHKreader" onchange="changePermissions(@item.SecureFolderID)" checked />
    }
    else
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="canRead_@item.SecureFolderID" class="CHKreader" onchange="changePermissions(@item.SecureFolderID)" />
    }
</td>
<td>
    @if (singleItem != null && singleItem.FolderWrite)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="canWrite_@item.SecureFolderID" class="CHKwriter" onchange="changePermissions(@item.SecureFolderID)" checked />
    }
    else
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="canWrite_@item.SecureFolderID" class="CHKwriter" onchange="changePermissions(@item.SecureFolderID)" />
    }
</td>

<td>
    @if (singleItem != null && singleItem.ExpireDate != null)
    {
        <input class="datepick" id="expDate-@item.SecureFolderID" onchange="changePermissions(@item.SecureFolderID)" value="@singleItem.ExpireDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
    }
    else
    {
        <input class="datepick" id="expDate-@item.SecureFolderID" onchange="changePermissions(@item.SecureFolderID)" />
    }
</td>
```

I know the copy/paste code is not that clean. The textbox could be filled in with a variabele, which could remain empty if the DB record is as well. But I don't know if that makes the code more 'readable' or if such a method works for the Checkbox as well.

Comment: What are `singleItem` and `item`?

Comment: custom class objects, defined above the wall of code you see above.

Comment: So neither are loop variables?

Comment: Both of them are, truth be told. Both of them change every iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the razor boolean attributes:

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" id="canRead_@item.SecureFolderID" class="CHKreader" onchange="changePermissions(@item.SecureFolderID)" checked="@(singleItem != null && singleItem.FolderRead)" />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="canWrite_@item.SecureFolderID" class="CHKwriter" onchange="changePermissions(@item.SecureFolderID)" checked="@(singleItem != null && singleItem.FolderWrite)" />
</td>
<td>
    <input class="datepick" id="expDate_@item.SecureFolderID" onchange="changePermissions(@item.SecureFolderID)" value="@((singleItem != null && singleItem.ExpireDate != null)?singleItem.ExpireDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"):null)" />
</td>
```

Going further, if item/singleitem are coming from an Enumerable, there is probably a better way to generate the Ids as well.  Especially if you want them to post back into a nice object.  Remove the classes, remove the onchange handler.

```
@for(var i=0;i<Model.Count;i++)
{
  <tr data-something="@item.SecureFolderID">
    <td>
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m[i].FolderRead)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m[i].FolderWrite)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m[i].ExpireDate,new{type="date"}) // HTML5 date w/datepicker for browsers that support it
    </td>
  </tr>
}

<style>
 #mytable td:first-child input { CHKreader styles here };
 #mytable td:nth-child(2) input { CHKwriter styles here };
 #mytable td:nth-child(3) input { datepick styles here };
/* Optionally use these instead
 input[name*="FolderRead"] { CHKreader styles here };
 input[name*="FolderWrite"] { CHKwriter styles here };
 input[name*="ExpireDate"] { datepick styles here };
*/
</style>
<script>
  $('#mytable').on("change","input",function(){
    var folderid=$(this).closest("tr").data("something");
    changePermissions(folderid);
  });
</script>
```

You could also use an EditorFor on the date and create your own template if you prefer that route.

Comment: Yes, I already changed it to something like what you just typed, though your solution is much more refined. Thank you.